# Validating a textbox using regex, to contain only numerical values which can only contain a set amount of values

Tags: c#, sql, regex, validation

I am trying to validate a contact number textbox to hold only 11 digits. I have validated the program to say when a user has entered no value or when the user hasnt used a non-numeric value. I am currently trying to use regex to validate it to only hold numerical values and to be 11 digits long but I have been having problems with the logic, I have worked through the logic over and over trying to use if loops and other functions in multiple ways but I am really new to regex and I'm sure the problem is with that. Thanks.

**Here is the regex code:**

```
Regex checkContactNum = new Regex(@"[0-9]\\d{11}");
```

**Here is the whole method code:**

```
   private void addEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Regex checkContactNum = new Regex(@"[0-9]\\d{11}");

             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addFirstName.Text) ||
                            string.IsNullOrEmpty(addLastName.Text) || 
               string.IsNullOrEmpty(addRole.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(addContactNum.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a value");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addFirstName.Text))
                {
                    errorFirstName.Visible = true;
                    addFirstName.Focus();
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addLastName.Text))
                {
                    errorLastName.Visible = true;
                    addLastName.TabIndex = 0;
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addRole.Text))
                {
                    errorRole.Visible = true;
                    addRole.TabIndex = 1;
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addContactNum.Text))
                {
                    errorContactNum.Visible = true;
                    addContactNum.TabIndex = 2;
                }
            }
            if (!int.TryParse(addContactNum.Text, out parsedValue) && addContactNum.Text != "")//checks if there is any numeric values
            {                                                           //cant have if null or empty due to message box, need a way to exclude
                MessageBox.Show("This is a number only field");
                errorContactNum.Visible = true;
            }
            if (checkContactNum.IsMatch(addContactNum.Text) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This needs to be 11 digits long.");
                errorContactNum.Visible = true;
            }
            if (addFirstName.Text != "" && addLastName.Text != "" && addRole.Text != "" && addContactNum.Text != "" && !int.TryParse(addContactNum.Text, out parsedValue) && checkContactNum.IsMatch(addContactNum.Text) == true)
            {
                    errorFirstName.Visible = false;
                    errorLastName.Visible = false;
                    errorRole.Visible = false;
                    errorContactNum.Visible = false;

                    string addEmployee = "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName, Role, DateOfHire)" +
                            "VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Role, @DateOfHire)";


                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(addEmployee, conn);
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addFirstName.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addLastName.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Role", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addRole.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfHire", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addDateOfHire.Text;

                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();

                    addFirstName.Text = String.Empty;
                    addLastName.Text = String.Empty;
                    addContactNum.Text = String.Empty;
                    addRole.SelectedIndex = 0;

                    addFirstName.TabIndex = 0;
                    addRole.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Report Bug to maker.");
        }
```

Image 1:
[This is showing my program refusing to take 11 digits.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wopkt.png)

Comment: Only eleven digits can be validated with `@"^\d{11}$"`. Yours `@"[0-9]\d{11}"` just matches any chunk of 12 digits. And you have ``\\`` in a verbatim string literal - so your regex matches a digit, then ``\`` symbol, and then 11 `d` characters.

Comment: or, as you are parsing it to ineger, you can just check if this integer is not bigger than 99999999999

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have changed the regex expression to the one you have listed but I am not more than sure its something with my validation as the same problem occurs.

Comment: @VDN I have been through other solutions but I would like to use regex with this code for certain reasons.

Comment: Use my regex with `!checkContactNum.IsMatch(addContactNum.Text)` (you now check if it equals `true`, but I think you need to check if it is `false`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either:

```
@"^\d{11}$"
```

or

```
@"^[0-9]{11}$"

private void TextBox1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, @"^\d{11}$"){
        //  matches
    } 
    else
    {
        // doesn't mstch
    }
}
```

for a complete validation I recommand doing something like this:

```
string err = "";
if(TxtFirstname.Text.Trim()=="") err+= "....\r\n"  ;
if(TxtLastname.Text.Trim()=="") err+= "....\r\n" ; 
if(!Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, @"^\d{11}$")) err+= "....\r\n" ; 
.
.
.
if(err=="")
   //Save It
else
   MessageBox.Show(err);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as I am assuming this is correct I now know its not an error with the regex expression I used but with my validation, I am assuming again the validation error is something to do with my IF loops which I've been through and it made sense to me.

Comment: @JordanCoaten I edited my answer. actually you don't need that much if clauses.  if it matches do what ever you want otherwise show an error

Comment: Yeah I'm not too great at coding yet, I see where I went wrong and the logic is quite terrible. Thank you so much for helping me with my problem. :-)

Comment: @JordanCoaten for validating all fields I edited my answer with a simple solution. please have a look

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I am trying to understand the simplified code but I am not too sure what .Trim does?

Comment: @JordanCoaten .Trim() means remove whitespace from the begining and end of the text. wihich means that even if the user has entered several space  characters in textbox (although the value is not equal to `""` any more) but its trimed valued is still `""`. this was only for demonstration that you can have a error adding each error for each validation. if at the end the error variable is empty well then there were no errors. otherwise you have all error messages in it that you can show to the user

Comment: That was going to be another validation that I needed to complete after this, so thank you for teaching me what that means. :-)

Comment: I will modify my code now and let you know when I get it working, and again thank your for time and help.

Comment: I wanted to upvote for the answer but I only have 12 rep :'O when I get 3 more rep I will make sure to upvote to give back as I know it helps.

Comment: @JordanCoaten Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have properly utilized the code and continued with other validation, again I thank you very much.

Comment: happy to hear that. I'm glad I could help.